# I am doing Unit Testing in QT test for c++, I am getting Fatal error?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt-creator, fatal-error

The detailed problem is given here

```
void HostManagerTesting::TestAstmIsrGet()
    {
        cout<<"\n//***   "<<__func__<<"  func called   ***//\n"<<endl;
        int iReturn;
        cout<<"\n________________Case_1________________\n"<<endl;
        Astm_obj.ut_set_AstmIsrGet(100);
        iReturn=Astm_obj.AstmIsrGet(10,EOT);
        QCOMPARE(iReturn,0);
        cout<<"\n//***   "<<__func__<<"  func Done   ***//\n"<<endl;
    }
```

I am testing this function , Astm_obj is an class object ,ut_set_AstmIsrGet(100) is function created by me for seting a global variable

```
void Astm::ut_set_AstmIsrGet(int m)
{
  IsrStatus=m;
}
```

The Actual function I am testing is this

```
int Astm::AstmIsrGet ( int a, UCHAR uc )
{
  SHORT sReport;

  sReport = 0;

  if (IsrStatus == ISR_IDLE)
  {
    if (uc == EOT || uc == ACK || uc == NAK || uc == ENQ)
    {
      IsrBufIn [0] = uc;
      IsrBufInPos  = 1;
      sReport = 1;
      cout<<"uc=eot";
      goto EXIT;
    }
    
  }

EXIT:           

  if (sReport)
  {
    IsrBufInData = IsrBufInPos;
    IsrStatus = ISR_WAIT;
    /* Warns the ASTM automaton of the end of the rx */
    sem_post ( &AstmSemRxEnded );
  } 
  return( 0);
}
```

It should return 0 , But all I get is fatal error .

This is the error I am getting

```
**________________Case_1________________
=== Received signal at function time: 1ms, total time: 24ms, dumping stack ===
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.0.90-0ubuntu1) 12.0.90
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 24482
(gdb) QFATAL : HostManagerTesting::TestAstmIsrGet() Received signal 11
         Function time: 0ms Total time: 24ms
FAIL!  : HostManagerTesting::TestAstmIsrGet() Received a fatal error.
   Loc: [Unknown file(0)]
Totals: 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 152ms
********* Finished testing of HostManagerTesting *********
=== End of stack trace ===
16:29:54: /home/chaithanya/Documents/QT/build-HostManagerTesting-Desktop-Debug/HostManagerTesting crashed.**
```

I feel that the problem exists in passing the arguments, am I passed it correctly , is there any other way to pass arguments ?

Comment: "Signal 11" is a *crash* (segmentation fault). You need to tell the unit-test framework you use to not catch the signal, and then catch the crash in the debugger instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest. Unlikely someone will have an answer ready and then not post it just to let you wait a bit more. All answers are provided "as soon as possible", pushing for it looks a little impolite (why your quesiton is any more urgent than others?)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah , it seems to be bit impolite , I agree with that , This is my first question in Stack overflow , I will remember that from now on . Thanks for correcting . Also it will be help full if you provide solution my question .

Comment: You could probable speed up things, if you provide a [mre], with emphasis on "complete", "minimal" and "reproducible". What did you find when you did what Someprogrammerdude suggested? Oh, you did not yet? Then go ahead, and [edit] your question to add the outcome.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you , Hope I made my question precise.

Comment: @SomeprogrammerdudeThanks for suggestion , but I am not able to get what you are saying , how to skip catching the signal in QT ? can you provide some details !

Comment: That is not a [mre], which must include anything for us to copy and reproduce without the need to add any line.